# Why does updating a dictionary remove the rest of the dictionaries from my nested array?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested, for-in-loop

I have a json file with players structured as so

```
[
  {
    "Player_Name": "Rory McIlroy",
    "Tournament": [
      {
        "Name": "Arnold Palmer Invitational presented by Mastercard",
        "Points": "68.10",
        "Salary": "12200.00"
      },
      {
        "Name": "World Golf Championships-Mexico Championship",
        "Points": "103.30",
        "Salary": "12200.00"
      },
      {
        "Name": "The Genesis Invitational",
        "Points": "88.60",
        "Salary": "12200.00"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Farmers Insurance Open",
        "Points": "107.30",
        "Salary": "12200.00"
      },
      {
        "Name": "World Golf Championships-HSBC Champions",
        "Points": "138.70",
        "Salary": "12400.00"
      },
      {
        "Name": "The ZOZO Championship",
        "Points": "103.40",
        "Salary": "12300.00"
      }
    ]
  }]
```

When I run this code

```
import json
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from itertools import groupby

# using json open the player objects file and set it equal to data
with open('Active_PGA_Player_Objects.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

with open('Players_DK.json') as json_file:
    Players_DK = json.load(json_file)

results = []

for k,g in groupby(sorted(data, key=lambda x:x['Player_Name']), lambda x:x['Player_Name']): 
    results.append({'Player_Name':k, 'Tournament':[i['Tournament'][0] for i in g]})

for obj in results:
    for x in Players_DK:
        if obj['Player_Name'] == x['Name']:
            obj['Average'] = x['AvgPointsPerGame']

i = 0
points_results = []
while i < len(results):
    j = 0
    while j < len(results[i]['Tournament']):
        difference =  (int(float(results[i]['Tournament'][j]['Points'])) -  (results[i]['Average']))
        points_results.append(round(difference,2))
        j += 1
    i += 1

with open('PGA_Player_Objects_w_Average.json', 'w') as my_file:
    json.dump(results, my_file)
```

my list comes back like this

```
[{
    "Player_Name": "Rory McIlroy",
    "Tournament": [
      {
        "Name": "Arnold Palmer Invitational presented by Mastercard",
        "Points": "68.10",
        "Salary": "12200.00"
      }
    ],
    "Average": 96.19
  }]
```

Can someone explain to me why when I update the specific dictionary it deletes all but the first value from the nested `Tournament` list? My goal here is to add each players average to their corresponding dictionary so that I can take each average and subtract it from each score. When I try to do this though I'm only able to perform it on the one value left in the list.

Comment: Also any recommendation on iteration? Nested loops are gross.

Comment: Why are you using `while` loops??? In any case, it always helps you you explain what your code is supposed to do.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I enjoy the suffering

Comment: Anyway, this happens because you use `[i['Tournament'][0] for i in g]`. So you only ever take the first item in that list, and that will be repeated as many times as there are players wiht that name in the group-by

Comment: Ah wow I was using the code before to combine all the names into one and then I created a json file and was trying to do it again! @juanpa.arrivillaga

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for what it's worth, I'd go back and really think about what each line is really doing. You're also making things harder on yourself by calling variables `obj` or `x`.  Calculating the average can be done like:

```
for player in data: # data is poorly named, try players or players_data
    player['Average'] = sum(float(tourny['Points']) for tourny in player['Tournament']) / len(player['Tournament'])
    for tourny in player['Tournament']:
        tourny['Difference'] = float(tourny['Points']) - float(player['Average'])
```

leaving you with:

```
{'Player_Name': 'Rory McIlroy', 
 'Tournament': [{
     'Name': 'Arnold Palmer Invitational presented by Mastercard', 
     'Points': '68.10', 
     'Salary': '12200.00', 
     'Difference': -33.46666666666667},
    {
     'Name': 'World Golf Championships-Mexico Championship', 
     'Points': '103.30', 
     'Salary': '12200.00', 
     'Difference': 1.7333333333333343}, # .....etc 
  'Average': 101.566666666666666
}
```

When you use names in your code that describe what they're representing, a huge number of optimizations become immediately obvious. Give it a go!